# Contract creation with parameters from web usning sendTransaction

Tags: web3js

I have a contract code with 3 params (_orcid , _researchID , _name )

```
var _orcid = "param1" ;
var _researchID = "param2" ;
var _name = "param3";
var browser_uactor_sol_actorContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getName","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"kill","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_keyword","type":"string"}],"name":"addKeyword","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_relate","type":"string"}],"name":"addRelated","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_orcid","type":"string"},{"name":"_researchID","type":"string"},{"name":"_name","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"}]);
var browser_uactor_sol_actor = browser_uactor_sol_actorContract.new(
   _orcid,
   _researchID,
   _name,
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: '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', 
     gas: '4300000'
   }, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 })
```

I am trying to créate a contract from HTML page with

```
hash =web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: '0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',gas: '0xDBBE2', data: code, _orcid: '12345', _researchID : 'b0978', _name: 'myName' });
```

The contract is created, but the params are not loaded on it. I do not know how these areguments have to be added within web3.eth.sendTransaction.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: you're trying to call a function of the smart-contract?

Answer (score 1):

@Sepultura  Finally I did it, I deployed a new contract from a web site with all the parameters. I didn´t use sendTransaction but new, this is the code:

`function addActor(){
        var address = document.getElementById('add').value;
        var _orcid = '12345' ;
        var _researchID = '12345' ;
        var _name = 'Jon' ;
        var code= '0x606060405....544fd506e7e40029';
        var contract= web3.eth.contract(actorABI).new( _orcid, _researchID, _name,{from: address, data: code, gas: '0xDBBE2'});
        hash= contract.transactionHash;
        var trx= web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash);`

In order to check the new contract I run:

```
 var abi =[{"constant":false,"inputs...."type":"constructor"}];
console.log("ABI: "+abi);
var MyContract3 = eth.contract(abi);
console.log(MyContract3);
var contractInstance3 = MyContract3.at("0x1f2a50d8deb332d78466fc2077eb2152cb05fa39");
console.log("Instancia3:"+contractInstance3.address);

console.log("Name:"+contractInstance3.getName.call());
console.log("Creador:"+contractInstance3.getCreator.call());
```

This is the console output:

> ABI: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[objectObject],[object Object]
>   [object Object]
>   Instancia3:0x1f2a50d8deb332d78466fc2077eb2152cb05fa39
>   Name:Jon
>   Creador:0x767c5be07b8603782f9c69a1ed1fd9b759ba3057
>   true

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to call a contract-function from a web-application, it should work this way:

```
let _orcid = "param1" ;
let _researchID = "param2" ;
let _name = "param3";

// init web3, http-provider
let web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('192.168.1.10:8042'));

// init contract
let contract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getName","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"kill","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_keyword","type":"string"}],"name":"addKeyword","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_relate","type":"string"}],"name":"addRelated","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_orcid","type":"string"},{"name":"_researchID","type":"string"},{"name":"_name","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"}]);

// set address of the contract
contract.at('0x0000000...');

// call function
contract.myFunction(_orcid, _researchID, _name, (error, result) => {
    // finished
});
```

First you need to init web3 with your http-provider (which is a running node you can connect to). You need the IP-address of that node and the RPC-Port of the HTTP-RPC-Server.

Then you can get the contract instance from web3, but you also have to set the address of the contract (where the contract is saved in the blockchain).

Finally you're able to call your smart-contract functions.

If you running a private node by your own, you have to make sure, that you configured it proberly, so that the RPC-HTTP-Server is startet, the web3-API is unlocked and your node is accepting requests from outside.

Here is a example of how I start my node, but keep in mind that it accepts requests from **everyone**, which is a **high security risk** if the node is accessible from the internet:

```
geth --identity "node1" --fast --networkid 15 --datadir /home/pi/ethereum-private/node --nodiscover --rpc --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpcapi "eth,web3,net" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcport "8042" --port "30303" --unlock 0 --password "/home/pi/ethereum-private/node/password.txt" --ipcpath /home/pi/.ethereum/geth.ipc
```

**edit**: if you just wan't to deploy a Contract, you can use a Framework like Truffle. I'm not going into detail, but [here](http://chainskills.com/2017/04/03/create-and-deploy-a-smart-contract-66/) is a good tutorial.

Comment: I am trying to créate a new contract with some parameters, I do not want to use an existing contract.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I am trying to create a new contract with some parameters. I can also create the contract using this, but the parameters are no loaded in the contract  `MyContract = web3.eth.contract(actorABI);
contact = MyContract.new(['param1'], ['param2'],['param3'],{from: '0x00000000000000000',gas: '0xDBBE2', data: code});`

Comment: you need to deploy the contract on the blockchain, you can't do that like this, see the link I postet for a tutorial

Comment: The contract is created in the privite blockchain that I have.  <br/>   I was reading the API info [link](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction) for web3.eth.sendTransaction where I find:   <br/>   data: String - (optional) Either a byte string containing the associated data of the message, or in the case of a contract-creation transaction, the initialisation code.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do ... so you have your contract deployed on the blockchain? What is the address of the contract?

Comment: Yes I want to deploy a contract, the address is showed in the page using this code that is trigered with a botton:<br>   `var receipt= web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash);
  if (receipt!=null){
   document.getElementById('addNewActor').innerText ="Trx:"+ receipt.contractAddress;
  }`

Comment: of you wan't to deploy a contract follow the tutorial in the link I posted, otherwise I can't help you with that - sorry.

Comment: Once I have the contract address I go to the console to run this:    `var abi =[{"constant":false,"inputs.....}];     
console.log("ABI: "+abi);    
var MyContract3 = eth.contract(abi);   
console.log(MyContract3);  
var contractInstance3 = MyContract3.at("0x392f2435b3126685f7b6092804758ee3a09ea14f");
console.log("Instancia3:"+contractInstance3.address);
  <br/>  
console.log("Name:"+contractInstance3.getName.call());
console.log("Creador:"+contractInstance3.getCreator.call());`

Comment: Can some one else help me with the original question?    I am deploying a new contract from a web site, but contract params are not loaded in the contract

Comment: I don't think you can deploy a contract from a website, you can, however, call functions of your smart-contract from a website like I showed you in my answer